# HAPROXY traffic logs not logging in /var/log/haproxy.log

Tags: haproxy

I have below configuration in /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

```
# Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
# full configuration options online.
#
#   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
    # need to:
    #
    # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
    #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
    #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
    #   file. A line like the following can be added to
    #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    #    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
    #
    #log         127.0.0.1 local2
    log         /dev/log local0 debug

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000


#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend  main *:5000
    acl url_static       path_beg       -i /static /images /javascript /stylesheets
    acl url_static       path_end       -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js
    log /dev/log local0 debug
    option tcplog
    use_backend static          if url_static
    default_backend             app

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# static backend for serving up images, stylesheets and such
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend static
    balance     roundrobin
    server      static 127.0.0.1:4331 check

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend app
    balance     roundrobin
    server  app1 127.0.0.1:5001 check
    server  app2 127.0.0.1:5002 check
    server  app3 127.0.0.1:5003 check
    server  app4 127.0.0.1:5004 check
```

Configured rsyslog to send haproxy logs to /var/log/haproxy.log but I have see only haproxy service start stop logs, I don't see any logs which makes call to haproxy.

Answer (score 3):

I think because by default the haproxy uses the rsyslog, so a configuration with the following is needed:

Create/open a file as `vim /etc/rsyslog.d/haproxy-rsyslog.conf`, add the following snippet:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
$UDPServerAddress 0.0.0.0
local0.*    /var/log/haproxy.log
```

Restart the "rsyslog" service and the file should be created at "/var/log/haproxy.log".

Comment: I also had to restart haproxy in my case. Also it would be good check for the default logrotate settings in /etc/logrotate.d